# Setting up Rspec and Factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

This is what I have installed

```
Mac OS X ......... 10.9.2
Ruby ............. 1.9.3
Rails ............ 3.2.13
RSpec ............ 2.14.1
FactoryGirl ...... 4.4.0
```

This is what I've typed in the console so far.

```
$ rails new lab
$ cd lab
$ rspec --init
$ mkdir spec/factories
$ rails g model foo bar:integer
$ touch spec/foo_spec.rb
$ touch spec/factories/foo_factory.rb
```

I'm wondering how I make a FactoryGirl fixture to create a Foo Fixture.
I'm also wondering how to test that fixture with RSpec. I want to be able to test that bar is not nil, is a Fixnum, and equals a certain value.
I'm familiar with Test::Unit testing, but I was told to learn this just today.

Thanks for your time guys! Tell me if I left anything out.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the extensive documentation provided by [`FactoryGirl`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki)?

- [`FactoryGirl` wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki)
- [`FactoryGirl` general usage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage)
- [`FactoryGirl` 2.2](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory-girl-2-2-your-new-best-friend)
- [ThoughtBot advanced usage](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/mind-bending-factories)